# wait until function return result in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want `true` in the result , when function `checkLoading()` is call.

I have one jquery function:

```
function checkLoading() { 
            console.log('checking loading');
            if ($('div.vX.UC').css('display') === 'none') {
                console.log('Loading Complete');
                return true;
            } else {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    checkLoading();
                }, 500)
            }
        }
```

I am calling this function like below:

```
if(checkLoading()){
//   do something
}
```

But above function return `undefined` and not wait for the `final` return.

I tried this using `Deferred`. But this is not working, I tried below solution:

```
function checkLoading() {

            var dfrd1 = $.Deferred();
            console.log('checking loading');
            if ($('div.vX.UC').css('display') === 'none') {
                console.log('Loading Complete');
                return dfrd1.promise();
            } else {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    checkLoading();
                }, 500)
            }

            // return dfrd1.resolve();
            //return false;
        }

 checkLoading().done(function() {

                      // do something.
   });
```

But this solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: What is changing this to hide it? `$('div.vX.UC').css('display') === 'none'` that's where you want to return/callback out of, loops using timeout are never a good idea imho

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return the promise and [resolve](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolve/) it, not "[promise](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/)" it

```
var dfrd1 = $.Deferred();
function checkLoading(dfd) {
   console.log('checking loading');
   if ($('div.vX.UC').css('display') === 'none') {
     console.log('Loading Complete');
     return dfd.resolve();
   } else {
      setTimeout(function() {checkLoading(dfd)}, 500)
   }

   return dfd.promise();
}

checkLoading(dfrd1).then(function() {

});
```

Comment: `checkLoading().done(function() {debugger;};` never return at debugger; , i already tried this solution.

Comment: You would need to pass the deferred to the next calling of checkLoading, ie `checkLoading(dfrd1)` and use that passed deferred to call resolve() on instead of creating a new one and calling resolve on that one.

Comment: @chiragsatapara did that four you

Comment: @DrColossos, thanks for your answer , it's work for me. I just edit your answer , use `done` instead of `then`

Answer (score 2):

If not using promises, you can also traditionally use a callback.

```
function checkLoading(callback) { 
    console.log('checking loading');
    if ($('div.vX.UC').css('display') === 'none') {
        console.log('Loading Complete');
        callback();
    } else {
        setTimeout(function() {
            checkLoading();
        }, 500)
    }

}
```

Would be used like this:

```
checkLoading(function() {
    // do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You Should try like below :

```
function checkLoading() {
         var dfrd1 = $.Deferred();
         console.log('checking loading');
         if ($('div.vX.UC').css('display') === 'none') {
              console.log('Loading Complete');
              dfrd1.resolve("Loading Completed");
         } else {
              setTimeout(checkLoading, 500)
         }
         return dfrd1.promise();
    }
```